# How to capture triggered element via click event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trigerring an event in WordPress sub menus. When I Click one of the submenu, it should trigger a click event on another sub menu.

This is my current code:

```
<a href="#">Parent Category</a>

<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item-lidingo">
        <a href="#">Sub Cat 1</a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item-nacka">
        <a href="#">Sub Cat 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
  j('.menu-item-lidingo').click(function(e) {
    console.log(j(this).attr('class'));

    j('.woof_term_224 > label').click(function(e) {
      console.log(j(this).attr('class'));
    });

  });
```

The html code for the element that will be triggered looks like below:

```
<ul class="wcarchive-terms-list">
    <li class="wcarchive-term wcarchive-term-parent woof_term_224">
        <label class="wcarchive-term-label open">
            Lidingo
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I trigger a Click event from the sub menu, I want to check if `.wcarchive-term-label` has a class called `open`

Do you know how can i achieve this within the code:

```
  j('.menu-item-lidingo').click(function(e) {
    console.log(j(this).attr('class'));

    j('.woof_term_224 > label').click(function(e) {
      console.log(j(this).attr('class'));
    });

  });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/);

```
j('.woof_term_224 > label').click(function(e) {
      if($(this).hasClass("open")){
        console.log("this has been opened!");
      }
      console.log(j(this).attr('class'));
    });

j('.woof_term_224 > label').trigger("click");
```

Comment: yup. Thanks for that but do you know how can i check if the triggered element has an existing class called open?

Comment: ah, you could use .hasClass()

Answer (score 0):

It could be more better to use live click function like

```
j(document).on("click", ".woof_term_224 > label",function(e) {
      if($(this).hasClass("open")){
        console.log("this has been opened!");
      }
      console.log(j(this).attr('class'));
    });

j('.woof_term_224 > label').trigger("click");
```

Than this could be trigger by JQuery function too. 
Thanks